# Java Excluding 0 from a Random number loop -What issues can come with my solution?

Tags: java

Are there any issues with distribution or other problems that I'm oblivious to by doing this?

```
int exercise = number.nextInt(4);
int repetition = number.nextInt(30);

if(exercise == 0) {
  exercise = exercise + exercise + 1;
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here or what you perceive to be the problem - could you go into a little more detail?

Comment: *"This is my solution to the question"* What question?

Comment: I wanted to have a random number generated between 1 and 4. however, 0 comes up. So, to deal with that, I added the 1 and a random to the random number (although, now looking at it, I think i need to change that).

The other issue, i had was, when I set it at nextInt(4). my number 4 option would not come up. When I set it to nextInt(5), my option 4 would come up.

I am unclear why this happens, because my understanding is that it will randomly generate a number between 0 and 4 for nextin(4)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that if clause. If you want to make sure that your "range" of random values doesn't start with 0 ... then simply do:

```
int exercise = number.nextInt(4) + 1
```

makes sure that exercise is in [1, 4] for example.

Comment: I read on here, that the problem with that is, you'll have 1 over represented. So i wanted to add another random number to it and 1, to reduce that.

Comment: @phpvirgin All this does is shift all the numbers up 1. It doesn't cause any numbers to be more common.